# Positive look-behind in R that includes non-ascii characters

Tags: regex, r, arabic, stringr

I am trying to extract the first group of non-whitespace characters that follows an Arabic string for each text in a set of about 2,100 total texts. Some of these texts contain the string, while others do not. This would be a very easy task, using `str_extract` from the `stringr` package, if the string were in English. However, for some reason this function doesn't work when using an Arabic string within the look-behind pattern:

```
library(stringr)
test_texts <- c(
    "My text كلمة containing some Arabic",
    "My text كلمة again containing some Arabic",
    "My text that doesn't contain any Arabic"
)
str_extract(test_texts, "(?<=text )\\S+")
# [1] "كلمة" "كلمة" "that"
str_extract(test_texts, "(?<=containing )\\S+")
# [1] "some" "some" NA    
str_extract(test_texts, "(?<=كلمة )\\S+") #returns NAs even though string is there
# [1] NA NA NA
```

Note that this works if I'm not using a look-behind pattern:

```
str_extract(test_texts, "كلمة \\S+")
# [1] "كلمة containing" "كلمة again"      NA
```

Why does the Arabic mess things up only when using a look-behind pattern?

I am using R version 3.2.3, on OS X 10.11.3, and stringr version 1.0.0.

Comment: Seems like a `stringi` limitation (or locale issue?); they work fine with base regex with `perl = TRUE`: `regmatches(test_texts, gregexpr('(?<=كلمة )(\\S+)', test_texts, perl = TRUE))`

Comment: Weird... this works... `grepl("كلمة", test_texts)`

Comment: Yes I suspect it is something with stringi. That regmatches example works great though!

Comment: Actually, there is no point in using the lookbehind in this case, you can use a non-lookaround based regex `كلمة +(\\S+)` with `str_match`, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

It seems there is some issue how `str_extract` processes the right-to-left text inside the positive lookbehind. As a workaround, you may use `str_match` with a regex having a capturing group around the subpattern capture the value you need:

```
> res <- str_match(test_texts, "كلمة +(\\S+)")
> res[,2]
[1] "containing" "again"      NA
```

This solution allows matching the non-whitespace chunk even if there are more than 1 space after the Arabic word.

Comment: This works for my purposes, although I'm still curious what is causing it to not work using the lookbehind approach.

Comment: The issue is most likely is with how the ICU library deals with the Arabic input plus the fact this literal character sequence is inside a lookbehind that cannot have unknown length.

Answer (score 0):

You can grep for non-ascii characters like this:

```
str_extract(test_texts, "[^\001-\177]+")
[1] "كلمة" "كلمة" NA   

str_extract(test_texts, "(?<=[^\001-\177] )\\S+")
[1] "containing" "again"      NA
```

And this seems to work... just adding brackets to what you had. This may not be sufficient either since the characters can be in any order if they are in brackets.

```
str_extract(test_texts, "(?<=[كلمة] )\\S+")
[1] "containing" "again"      NA
```

Comment: Thanks - this is in the right direction but won't be sufficient because the texts I am actually working with contain more Arabic than just the string I want to match in the look-behind (I recognize I didn't make this clear in the question though!).

Comment: Interesting that it works with the brackets - although if I understand this correctly, what this look-behind regex matches is when any one of those four Arabic characters (ك، ل، م، ة) is followed by a single space, whereas I need it to match when that exact word is followed by a space. But regardless it is odd that Arabic character sets using "[]" work when my example does not.